# How to send a POST in .net vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What i am trying to do is get my user to enter in a phone number and message and then post it to text marketer which send the message.

at the moment if i use a response.redirect the message sense..

```
response.redirect("http://www.textmarketer.biz/gateway/?username=*****&password=*****&message=test+message&orig=test&number=447712345678")
```

However, i do not want to send the user there. all i want to do it post the data to the url and that's all for now and the user stay on the current page.

Any help?

Comment: the example you posted does not `POST` the data. That's a GET request (data is in the url/query string). If you need to POST, as you say, take a look at my modified answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

actually, you don't have to do this server side (vb), just plain html will do the trick:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <form action="http://google.com" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" value="somevalue"/>
            <input Type="submit" value="Submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

this will post the data (and in effect, redirect) to google.com.

Maybe you could use client script (jQuery) - $.ajax() or $.post(). but I think you will face cross domain restrictions (there is a workaround but its not that clean and straightforward).

Another is using the HttpWebRequest class. This is server side and the post will originate from your server instead of the client (as what the 1st approach will do). upon calling request.GetResponse(), you can retrieve the output from the remote server and render it on your page. But if you want to post and redirect to the remote url then I guess you should use the first approach.

EDIT:

try this in VB:

```
Option Infer On
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Text


Public Class Test

    Private Sub TESTRUN()
        Dim s As HttpWebRequest
        Dim enc As UTF8Encoding
        Dim postdata As String
        Dim postdatabytes As Byte()
        s = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.textmarketer.biz/gateway/")
        enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
        postdata = "username=*****&password=*****&message=test+message&orig=test&number=447712345678"
        postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(postdata)
        s.Method = "POST"
        s.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        s.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length

        Using stream = s.GetRequestStream()
            stream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
        End Using
        Dim result = s.GetResponse()
    End Sub
End Class
```

update2:

a GET request using HttpWebRequest in VB.net.

```
Dim s As HttpWebRequest
Dim username = "username=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("yourusername")
Dim password = "password=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("yourp@assword)!==&@(*#)!@#(_")
Dim message = "message=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("yourmessage")
Dim orig = "orig=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("dunno what this is")
Dim num = "number=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("123456")
Dim sep = "&"
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
sb.Append(username).Append(sep).Append(password).Append(sep)
sb.Append(message).Append(sep).Append(orig).Append(sep).Append(num)

s = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://www.textmarketer.biz/gateway/?" + sb.ToString())

s.Method = "GET"
Dim result = s.GetResponse()
```

Comment: I dont want the user to redirect. I want to just post the data to the url and thats all. Ideally server side, i will look into httpwebrequest, but i dont really want a request and i think i have attempted this but no sucess

Comment: does the remote server require authentication or something? or maybe a required cookie?

Comment: Nope sorry that has not worked either, dont really need a request from them either

Comment: could you at least tell us what the error/exception is? do you really need a `POST` operation? or a `GET` operation..

Comment: it might be because you're not supposed to send a `POST` request. I've updated my answer showing how to send a `GET` request...

Comment: Also yes it has to be a GET, il give ur new one a shot thanks

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the webrequest class. refer http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: I tried this exact example before i posted this question. I thought it would work but nothing.

Comment: are you getting any exception? check the uri that you are posting and the parameters that it expects.

Comment: I have i am copying the same parameters i used from when i used response.redirect, which sent sent message

Answer (score 1):

Don't do this server side, but client side using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

The [jQuery ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) library is quite good.

Comment: I have no experience with Ajax, so im not sure what it all means and where to start

Comment: Which is why i would prefer to find a server side option

Comment: @Beginner - you shouldn't be afraid to learn a new technology, especially if it is the right one...

Comment: if it is client side wouldnt anybody be able to look at the source and see my username and password and use the credits up?

Comment: @Beginner - Why do you think doing a `POST` would be more secure?

Comment: OK, I know this answer is almost 3 years old, but I ran into a scenario this month, and I realized that, much to my anguish, I **would'nt** be able to use jQuery Ajax in this case.
The ViewState in Asp.net would not change within an Ajax request, so **if** there were an UpdatePanel, it would misbehave.

Comment: AJAX is not usable when you need to perform a cross domain request