# Form POST with no submit button

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net, forms, webforms

I want integrate a payment gateway into my web app and found that thier integration required a front end form to submit the values across - In the app I don't current have a front end for the payment, just a load of back end VB.NET code that collects the info and passes it into a url for a similar payment gateway.

Being as the gateway relies on a form being posted I need to find a way to simulate this using only back end code, so my biggest question in regards to all this is, is it possible to submit (POST) a form without the user clicking a button?

The form required in the front end is:

```
<form method="post" action="https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp / orderstandard_utf8.asp" id=form1 name=form1>

<!-- general parameters: see Form parameters -->
<input type="hidden" name="PSPID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="ORDERID" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="AMOUNT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CURRENCY" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="LANGUAGE" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CN" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="EMAIL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERZIP" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERADDRESS" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERCTY" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERTOWN" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="OWNERTELNO" value="">

<!-- check before the payment: see Security: Check before the payment -->
<input type="hidden" name="SHASIGN" value="">

<!-- layout information: see Look and feel of the payment page -->
<input type="hidden" name="TITLE" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BGCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="TXTCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="TBLBGCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="TBLTXTCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BUTTONBGCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="BUTTONTXTCOLOR" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="LOGO" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="FONTTYPE" value="">

<!-- post payment redirection: see Transaction feedback to the customer -->
<input type="hidden" name="ACCEPTURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="DECLINEURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="EXCEPTIONURL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="CANCELURL" value="">

<input type="submit" value="" id=submit2 name=submit2>
</form>
```

Failing submitting the form without a button, would it then have the same effect if i re-directed to the action url once all the hidden fields were in place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a POST in .net vb?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108531/how-to-send-a-post-in-net-vb)

Comment: You could call the submit function of the form in javascript.

Comment: The url I have does not send paramaters as in the POST example - it sends the values of the hidden fields - if it sent them as params I'd be able to create a string builder but I need something that will behave like a form to pass the values across in the same way a form would if they were hidden fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using System.Net.WebClient is the easiest way to go.

```
Dim Url As String = "https://mdepayments.epdq.co.uk/ncol/test/orderstandard.asp"

Using Client As New WebClient
    Dim Params As New Specialized.NameValueCollection

    With Params
        .Add("PSPID", "")
        .Add("ORDERID", "")
        '......
    End With

    Dim Response As Byte() = Client.UploadValues(Url, "POST", Params)
    Dim ResponseText As String = (New Text.UTF8Encoding).GetString(Response)
End Using
```

Comment: The 'Params' collection I assume would act as the hidden fields so therefore I can drop the form altogether? Does that mean that when a form submits this is essentially what is happening in the background?

Comment: Yes and yes.  Maybe Params is a poor variable name.  Client.UploadValues() sends the name/value collection in the body of the request.  It does not send them as a query string.