# Passing data between .net and php

Tags: php, vb.net, web-services

I have a web server where there are a few php scripts. These scripts are web service whereby some data is passed and they return values in json format.

For e.g. : http://www.example.com/test.php?name=abcd&id=100

So far passing values in url is the method and its ok if there is short content. However if I have to pass 1 page worth of content/text to it then there must be another way.

Currently my code is:

```
Dim web_client As Net.WebClient = New Net.WebClient
Dim Info As String

Dim response As IO.Stream = web_client.OpenRead("http://example.com/auth.php?userid=102&password=123")

Dim stream_reader As New IO.StreamReader(response)
Info = stream_reader.ReadToEnd()

' Close the stream reader and its underlying stream.
stream_reader.Close()
response.Close()

print (Info)   ' info has output which is in json format
```

Is the above method ok and secure ? However if I wish to pass large amounts of data or the method is not secure then what should I do ?

Thank you.

Comment: You should use POST instead of GET when you send data. GET (which is what you're currently are doing) is for _getting_ data and POST is for _posting_ data.

Comment: I think you mis-understood the question. Right now I am passing data in url. How to pass it another way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send a POST in .net vb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108531/how-to-send-a-post-in-net-vb)