# How send request to server with xml.

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I need send this request to server :

```
POST http://localhost:444/xml HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: User-Agent: STORMWARE HTTP client. http://www.stormware.cz
STW-Authorization: Basic QDo=
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: http://localhost:444
Content-Length: 527
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: Keep-Alive

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
<dat:dataPack xmlns:dat="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/data.xsd" xmlns:stk="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/stock.xsd" xmlns:ftr="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/filter.xsd" xmlns:lStk="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/list_stock.xsd" xmlns:typ="http://www.stormware.cz/schema/version_2/type.xsd" id="00000001" ico="25313142" application="HTTP klient" version="2.0" note="Export zasob">
  <dat:dataPackItem id="00000001" version="2.0">
    <lStk:listStockRequest version="2.0" stockVersion="2.0">
      <lStk:requestStock/> 
    </lStk:listStockRequest> 
  </dat:dataPackItem> 
</dat:dataPack>
```

I got data to HttpClient like this, but I dont know how send xml.

```
        StringContent myContent = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"....";
        HttpClient myClient = new HttpClient();
        Uri myUri = new Uri("http://desktop-t3ipeqk:444/xml");
        myClient.PostAsync(myUri, myContent);

        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("STW-Autorization", "Admin admin");
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Host", "http://desktop-t3ipeqk:444");
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Length", "527");
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Pragma", "no-cache");
        myClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
```

I will be happy for any advice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108531/how-to-send-a-post-in-net-vb

Comment: It looks like you've got some existing code for doing this. But you haven't explained how it's not working. Does it give an error? How does it not work as expected? Oh, and if you want to change the request headers, do it *before* you make your PostAsync call. And you need to await the results of the PostAsync. And you shouldn't instantiate a new HttpClient every time you need to call the API. If you're not familiar with HttpClient, it's better to use a library that wraps it properly such as [Flurl.Http](http://tmenier.github.io/Flurl/fluent-http/).

Comment: The sending should be no different then sending any data using HttpClient.  All you did was to add additional headers to the message beofre sending the message.  the headers are used for the client and server to negotiate a common mode of operation rather than using the server default mode.