# How to send Get Form Request with vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, forms, get

I want to send a standard HTML GET form using my vb.net backend, but dont know how regular html forms work with vb.net Can someone give me a high level overview so I can create this?

I have made a form completely standard html form with two inputs username and password and a submit input.

How would I access these variables in vb.net from here?

```
<form name="LoginForm" action="Site.master.vb" method="get" onclick="Update_Login">
  <input type="text" name="username" ID="txtLogin1" class="formfield"/>
  <input type="password" name="passphrase" ID="txtPass1" class="formfield"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login" ID="btnLogin1">
</form>
```

I just want to submit the form with GET on vb.net

Comment: onclick="Update_Login" is a public sub in my vb.bet backend

Comment: Have a look at this question on asp .net : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209301/how-to-post-a-form-from-html-to-aspx-page it should give you a way forwards although there are several ways of doing this depending on what flavour of asp .net (or other tech) you want to use

Comment: Please check this answer but it's POST method
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6108680/6923146